# How to send a specific id of element to Ajax in Ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm a Ruby user. I want to send a specific id of element to  Ajax in Ruby. I have a several "lessons" and each lesson has a button called "btn-class-enter". Whenever each button is clicked, it calculates difference between time.now and start_time. If it is shorter than 15 min, it allows user to go to the class room.

The way Ajax receives which lesson_id it has to see is via $(this).text(), meaning I make a "btn-class-enter" button with string <%=lesson.id%>.

But in this situation, the button looks really ugly and it has to be something like "Enter Class Button" without any id number to the users.

How can I send a specific id of element to Ajax in Ruby? I put what I've done so far here!

```
<a href="#" class="btn blue btn-class-enter"><%=lesson.id%></a>

<script>

$(".btn-class-enter").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
           url: "<%= classenter_path %>", // Route to the Script Controller method
          type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
          data: { lesson_id: $(this).text() }, // This goes to Controller in params hash, i.e. params[:lesson_id]
      complete: function() {},
       success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                  if (data.file_content == "false") {
                    $("#processing").html("<h2>Please join the class 15 min before the session.</h2>")
                  alert("Please join the class 15 min before the session.")
                  }
                  else{

                  window.location = "http://www.wowwow.com/classes/classroom" + data.lesson_id

                  }

                },
         error: function() {
                  alert("Ajax error!")
                }
    });
});

</script>
```

**Solution**

```
  <a href="#" class="btn blue btn-class-enter" data-lesson="<%=lesson.id%>">Enter Class</a>

<script>

    $(".btn-class-enter").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
               url: "<%= classenter_path %>", // Route to the Script Controller method
              type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
              data: { lesson_id: $(this).data("lesson") }, 
          complete: function() {},
           success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      if (data.file_content == "false") {
                        $("#processing").html("<h2>Please join the class 15 min before the session.</h2>")
                      alert("Please join the class 15 min before the session.")
                      }
                      else{

                      window.location = "http://www.wowwow.com/classes/classroom" + data.lesson_id

                      }

                    },
             error: function() {
                      alert("Ajax error!")
                    }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

!!

Comment: So your problem is solved right?

Comment: yes! I put the answer over there!